# Would a believing muslim woman who dresses immodestly go to hell?

Tags: sharia

If this was Muslim woman who believes in Allah and Islam, but keeps her religion to herself. Would she go to hell for assimilating with non-Muslims?

Comment: This question is difficult to answer without more specifics on what is meant by "keeping her religion to herself" and "assimilating."

Answer (score 1):

No one can say who will and will not go to hell.  This is only with Allah, unless he revealed to us who will specifically be in hell i.e. Firown, Abu Lahab and his wife etc...

One of the ways a believing woman is recognized, is by her dress.

Allah in Surah an-Nur 24:31 specifically mentions to **tell the BELIEVING WOMEN** and gives the ruling of protecting her adornments and covering her head and chest and body.

From this ayah, Allah gives one of the descriptions of a believing woman of being hijab.

But modesty isn't restricted to only clothes, it also has to do with her manners.  How she carries herself, how she talks, walks and so on.  Modesty is wide issue.

Throughout he Quran, Allah says **"Those who believe AND do righteous deeds..."**  Mere belief isn't enough, every person has to also practice.

Simply saying "I believe" but not act is laziness and there's no excuse for it unless it's a medical problem.

Allahoalim